# inserting date in MySQL using Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, date

I have the following code:

```
    my $tdate = $fields[0]; 
print "$tdate\n"; 
my $trade_dt=UnixDate($tdate,"%Y-%m-%d"); 
# my $trade_dt = DATE(\"$tdate\"); 
print "$trade_dt\n"; 
my $ins_rec = "INSERT IGNORE INTO $tblname(\`trade_dt\`,\`symbol\`) va +lues (?,?);"; 
my $sth=$dbh->prepare($ins_rec); 
$sth->execute($trade_dt,$symbol); 
$sth->finish;
```

and when I run it, I get the following message:

```
"10/14/2011" Use of uninitialized value $trade_dt in concatenation (.) or string at + Set.data.pl line 42, <FIN> line 1.
```

any thoughts on how I can fix it....it is obviously reading the date correctly from the file as the print statement shows the correct date for tdate which is reading from the csv file I have, but the conversion to trade_dt is not correct, is it?

Comment: There's no need to escape the backticks in your SQL statement. Backticks aren't special characters when used in a quoted string. Also, have you considered using something like DBIx::Class for your database interaction? It will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `UnixDate()` is returning `undef` because it can't parse the date you're giving it.  I suspect the problem is that your date string is surrounded by double quotes, and they're throwing the parser off.  Get rid of the quotes (using something like `$tdate =~ s/^"(.*)"$/$1/;`) and see if that helps.